# Understanding the battery report on my vehicle

Tags: honda, battery, crv, battery-testing

Had two questions about a battery report I received on my vehicle. The technician suggested I drive my vehicle more. I was hoping to understand why the report made him think that.

- The battery is rated 450, and there were 762 cold cranking amps(CCA). I was wondering if that number is low?
- Secondly, the gauge below the words "Good Battery" in the square box seems to be on the low side. What exactly is that measuring?

The voltage seems to be OK.

[image: Battery Readout from 2022 Honda CRV]

[image: Top of factory battery 2022 Honda CRV]

Comment: Which option package came on your CR-V? (ie: EX, Sport, Hybrid)

Comment: Also, if you can, could you put an image of the top of your battery? It would be good to know exactly which battery we're talking about here. I'll tell you, if your battery is rated at 450CCA, it shouldn't have more than that. To have 762CCA one rated at 450CCA seems HIGHLY suspect of the testing methods involved.

Comment: It wasn't a hybrid @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2. It was the EX-L. I did upload a photo of the battery. I think everything is visible even though there is a metal bar over part of the battery.

Comment: Does your CR-V have start/stop technology?

Comment: Yes - at traffic lights when I press the brake, the engine does stop to save fuel.

Answer (score 2):

**TL DR:** Your battery looks to be in good shape from what I see.

Here's what I *think* is at issue (or not, really) ...

I think whomever did the testing for your vehicle put the wrong vehicle code in the tester. There are several different CR-Vs for your year of vehicle (thus the questions in comments about which option package you had). 450 CCA would be for a regular CR-V which doesn't have stop/start technology installed. Those, like yours, which does have it, requires more CCAs.

I could not find a battery rating on your car, even though I did look through many different websites, even those which specialize in batteries. I think the reason for that is, it's just too new and most vehicles at the age of yours wouldn't require one yet as most OEM batteries last about 5 years or longer. 750-800 CCA seems about the right amount for your vehicle, but that'd be a guess on my part. The 762 CCA as measured means the battery should be in good shape.

I did find an [EV-LN2 battery on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0937CSJ21) which is rated at 660 CCA, so if that is what yours is rated at, the 762 CCA is very good.

12.48 vdc when the vehicle isn't running might be just a hair lower than I'd expect, but nothing to worry about. Most batteries when fully charged are around 12.5-13.1 vdc.

As far as the gauge in the picture, I think you're looking at it wrong. I'm pretty sure the tick pointing up to the 10 o'clock position is the low mark for if there's a problem. What you should be looking at is the thicker line between the two thin lines which arcs all the way over from left to right. This is showing it to be a FULL battery. Again, this could be off a bit because of the wrong input into their tool. If the battery was low, the thicker line would be off the pegged position and you'd have white space in there.

Comment: I apologize it’s not clearer but if you look at the the top of the battery it does says 450 CCA. You might have to zoom in. The link for the Amazon battery says it’s for 28 Volts so I think that might be mixed up? I did drive the car for about 15 minutes before bringing it to the shop. Not sure if that was adding to the 762 amps.

Comment: This Reddit link makes me think CCAs are rated at 0 degrees Fahrenheit. The battery was tested at ambient temperature https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicAdvice/comments/4pklzb/battery_tester_tested_cca_higher_than_rated/?rdt=62969

Comment: The "28 volts" on Amazon is wrong. It is a 12v battery. Amazon doesn't know what it's talking about 1/2 the time when it comes to car parts, but the image itself doesn't lie. If yours is a 450 CCA battery (as it says on the tag) that it is far in excess of it is not a bad thing. I still believe they did something wrong when testing it.

Comment: I ordered a battery tester that’s supposed to measure amps. It should be here on Saturday. I’m curious how it compares to the dealership test.  I will try it out and report back. I don’t know if it changes anything but my battery is an EFB and the report above says just flooded

Answer (score 1):

Bought a battery charger/maintainer (Noco Genuis 10) since I don't use the car frequently. Also bought a battery tester. Here is what it reported before charging the battery. The car had been idle most of the week except for a 12 minute excursion 3 days ago.

[image: Honda CRV Battery Report Before Charging]

CCA are measured at 0 degrees Fahrenheit. On the battery (see image above) it says to test at a rating of 225 Amps. These two reasons are probably why the measured amps are above the rated specification.

After charging, this is what my battery tester reported:

[image: After charging Honda CRV 2022]

The measured amps are now at 820. Not sure if the battery was overcharged.

To answer the original question:

1. I don't think 762 is too low of a number compared to 820.
2. I do agree with @Paulster2 on this one that the tick mark measures a low battery and my measured amps was above the rating.

I'm curious what my battery tester would report if I set the rating to 225 as instructed on the battery.

For what it's worth, my Klein multimeter reported a voltage 0.1 Volts greater than the battery tester measured minutes apart. I would be inclined to believe the multimeter was more accurate.